# Any issue with setTimeout calling itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, setinterval

I have read a handful of setTimeout questions and none appear to relate to the question I have in mind. I know I could use setInterval() but it is not my prefered option.

I have a web app that could in theory be running a day or more without a page refresh and more than one check a minute. *Am I likely to get tripped up if my function calls itself several hundred (or more) times using setInterval? Will I reach "stack overflow" for example?*

If I use setInterval there is a remote possibility of two requests being run at the same time especially on slow connections (where a second one is raised before the first is finished). I know I could create flags to test if a request is already active, but I'm afraid of false positives.

My solution is to have a function call my jquery ajax code, do its thing, and then as part of ajaxComplete, it does a setInterval to call itself again in X seconds. This method also allows me to alter the duration between calls, so if my server is busy(slow), one reply can set a flag to increase the time between ajax calls.

Sample code of my idea...

```
function ServiceOrderSync()
{   
    // 1. Sync stage changes from client with the server
    // 2. Sync new orders from server to this client
    $.ajax( {   "data": dataurl,
    "success": function(data)
            {   // process my data },
    "complete": function(data)
            {   
               // Queue the next sync
               setTimeout( ServiceOrderSync, 15000 );
            });

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't get a stack overflow, since the call isn't truly recursive (I call it "pseudo-recursive")

JavaScript is an event driven language, and when you call `setTimeout` it just queues an event in the list of pending events, and code execution then just continues from where you are and the call stack gets completely unwound before the next event is pulled from that list.

p.s. I'd strongly recommend using Promises if you're using jQuery to handle async code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the promise suggestion. I've never used promises - I've seen references of them but no experience of them. I am open to learning and trying but not within a production environment.

Comment: I'm reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise and looks like your suggestion is good one and something I need get comfortable with.

Comment: Every JS developer should, IMHO, but be aware that the jQuery promises implementation is not quite the same as the ES6 (and previous Promises/A) specification.

Comment: Google Chrome just recently made some updates to their debugger where using this method seems to increase the call stack. Not sure yet whether it's actually increasing a call stack. But counter to how I used to think setTimeout worked, using their debugger you can step back in the ServiceOrderSync stack to look at previous calls. Just FYI to look at if digging.